# Input's 'placeholder' font-family can't be set different than 'value' font-family (all other styles work though)

Tags: css, input, fonts, placeholder

This is a very specific problem I'm having styling an input field... it seems that even if I set the font-family different for 'placeholder' it always get's overridden by the input 'value' font-family — even when applying !important.  I am not asking how to style placeholders, that is easy, I am asking if anyone has been able to get the placeholder to use a different font-family than the input itself?

Here's the code I'm using:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyRvKm

```
<input type="text" class="search-field" placeholder="Search here" required>

.search-field {
    width: 230px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    border-left: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #060225;
}
.search-field::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.search-field:-moz-placeholder,
.search-field::-moz-placeholder,
.search-field:-ms-input-placeholder,
.search-field:placeholder-shown {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.06rem;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: @BrandonWebster read the post I've attached, it's the same case exactly, ,asking for font-family. And read the accepted answer, it solves splitting the rules.

Comment: And take care with `:placeholder-shown`, it's only to webkit desktop (it doesn't work in firefox, IE, Edge, android or iOS)

Comment: If you split the rules, it works, tested in your codepen, but I can't fork due I don't have user in codepen.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude OH I get what you mean!!  I will try that now.  Thank you so much!  I will also take care with placeholder-shown.

this is def. a duplicate according to that answer.  thanks a ton Marcos